Override the Agent side live agent window with custom solution
I am facing a challenge with implementing a custom agent-side chat window that displays real-time chat messages. I've mentioned creating a platform event to access real-time chat messages, but there's a limitation where I can't retrieve these messages in real-time due to how LiveChatTranscript objects work.
The issue lies in the fact that chat messages are only recorded in the LiveChatTranscript object once the session ends, even if I manually end the chat session by clicking the end chat button. This means that I am unable to access these messages as they happen.
Additionally, even though I've explored options like using the Streaming API to retrieve messages in real-time, Salesforce doesn't expose any push topics for this purpose. While there is a LiveChatTranscriptEvent object, it also doesn't provide access to real-time messages.
Here is the whole code:
trigger ChatMessageTriggerPE on LiveChatTranscript (After insert, After Update) {
List<ChatMessageEvent__e> events = new List<ChatMessageEvent__e>();
for (LiveChatTranscript lct : Trigger.new) {
    ChatMessageEvent__e event = new ChatMessageEvent__e();
    event.TranscriptId__c=lct.ChatKey;
    event.MessageBody__c = lct.Body;
    events.add(event);
}

if (!events.isEmpty()) {
    EventBus.publish(events);
}

}


    
        
            {message.MessageBody__c}
        
    

------------------------
// platformEventDemo.js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError } from 'lightning/empApi';
export default class PlatformEventDemo extends LightningElement {
@track data = [];
subscription = {};
channelName = '/event/ChatMessageEvent__e';

connectedCallback() {
    this.registerErrorListener();
    this.handleSubscribe();
}

registerErrorListener() {
    onError(error => {
        console.error('EMP API error: ', JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}

handleSubscribe() {
    const messageCallback = (response) => {
        this.handleMessage(response);
    };
    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
        console.log('Subscribed to platform event ', JSON.stringify(response));
        this.subscription = response;
    });
}

handleMessage(response) {
    const payload = response.data.payload;
    const formattedMessage = this.formatChatMessage(payload.MessageBody__c);
    this.data = [...this.data, { TranscriptId__c: payload.TranscriptId__c, MessageBody__c: formattedMessage }];
}

formatChatMessage(message) {
    // Remove the outer <p> tags from the message
    const lines = message.split('</p><p>');
    const formattedLines = lines.map(line => line.replace(/<p>|<\/p>/g, ''));
    return formattedLines.join('<br>');
}

disconnectedCallback() {
    this.handleUnsubscribe();
}

handleUnsubscribe() {
    unsubscribe(this.subscription, response => {
        console.log('Unsubscribed from ', JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}

}
